# Swift: Filter string by using start with

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array as follows:

```
let array = ["sam", "andrew", "character"]
```

And I want to get every element in the array that starts with a character I type

My problem is when i type "a" the output is "sam", "andrew", and "character".

I want to get the output to only be "andrew". (The string must start from left to right when searching)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to filter your array using [`hasPrefix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1540100-hasprefix)

```
var names = ["sam", "andrew", "character"]
var searchString = "a"

let filteredNames = names.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(searchString) })
print(filteredNames)
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use `string.hasPrefix(string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this in Swift 5:

```
let filteredNames = names.filter{$0.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil}
```